# ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, thread-safety

The below method is being called from various place in AsynTask. It is coded for Android. Getting ConcurrentModificationException. How to make this method thread safe

```
public static String saveJsonFile(File dir, String name, JSONObject data) {
        final File file = new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator + name);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (final IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedWriter printWriter = null;

        try {
            printWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 8192);
            // printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
            if (data != null)
                data.write(printWriter); // java.util.ConcurrentModificationException



                      ........
                      ........
```

Comment: Where is JSONObject.write()? I didn't get at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: It is a custom method added to write data to file. I dont have access to it now its compiled as Jar. Actually it is org.json.douglascrockford.JSONObject

Comment: @Vinayak.B There are two flavors of methods (other then constructor) in that class that mutate an underlying map. Do you ever invoke `put` or `popuplate` on the JSONObject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public static String saveJsonFile(File dir, String name, JSONObject data) {
    final File file = new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator + name);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (final IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedWriter printWriter = null;

    try {
        printWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 8192);

        synchronized(lock) {
            if (data != null)
                 data.write(printWriter); // java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                 //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your code `synchronized` on `data`:

```
synchronized(data) {
    try {
        printWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 8192);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck with this getting same exception